# Qt слот не запускает

Tags: qt

`qt` не "запускается" слот...
Имею не большой код, при клике, скачивается файл, должен, по крайней мере, но к слоту обращаться не хочет.

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QtGui>

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
     ui->setupUi(this);
 }

 MainWindow::~MainWindow()
 {
     delete ui;
 }

 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
 {
     QNetworkAccessManager accesManager;
     QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.5.0/images/qt-logo.png"));

     //Начинаем скачивание
     accesManager.get(request);

     //Вызов saveFile() когда докачалось...
     connect(&accesManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(saveFile_2()));

     //saveFile_2();
     //ui->label_text->setText("<h2>ТЕКСТы</h2>");
 }

 void MainWindow::saveFile(QNetworkReply *result)
 {
     ui->label_text->setText("<h2>скачен</h2>");

     QFile file("C://image.jpg");
     if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
     {
         ui->label_text->setText("<h2>Файл не записан </h2>");
         return;
     }

     file.write(result->readAll());

     file.flush();
     file.close();
     qDebug() << "File saving - completted";     
 }

 void MainWindow::saveFile_2()
 {
     ui->label_text->setText("<h2>скачан</h2>");
 }
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QFile>
#include <QtWebKit>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void saveFile(QNetworkReply *data);
    void saveFile_2();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

В чем проблема? Почему?

Comment: Коннектится нормально? Попробуйте послать свой сигнал связанный с этим слотом.

Насколько я помню, то сигнал/слот должны иметь одинаковую сигнатуру, но не уверен.

Comment: пробовал онклик сигнал обработать по другой кнопки, результат тот же, просто не выводит ни чего. Если указать не правильное название слота то при дебаги, при нажатии на кнопку вылазит мол неверный слот, так же и после скачивания. Нажал кнопку->скачалось->(неверное название слота)->дебаг пишет что мол нет такого слота, Нажал кнопку->скачалось->(правильно название слота)->ничего не происходит, хотя должна функция обрабатываться...

Comment: Буду с ПК попробую, но читая документацию, у меня возникает ощущение что запускать слоты(свои) нельзя...

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сделал классом, слот корректно обработался! Отправьте ваш комментарий в ответы, я помечу как правильный.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю решение Вашей проблеме кроется в том, как Вы выделяете память под `QNetworkAccessManager`. Дело в том, что память для него у Вас выделяется на стеке внутри функции. `Qt` честно соединяет Вам сигнал и слот, но вот сам объект `QNetworkAccessManager` удаляется со стека раньше, чем он может испустить сигнал. Попробуйте сделать `QNetworkAccessManager` переменной уровня класса, или же используйте new для выделения памяти в куче (не забудьте, что для последнего случая надо использовать `deleteLater()` во избежании утечек памяти!)